# Show the same information in tag filters as in question lists on the main sites

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

Tag filters on stackexchange.com are quite useful, or rather they're the only way to follow questions on multiple sites in a somewhat reasonable way without manually visiting each one.

But for some reason I don't understand they don't actually show the same information as just viewing the questions on the actual site. This is how a stackexchange.com filter looks like:

[image]

What's missing is the post score, the number of views and the avatar of the asking user. By far the most important one of these is the post score.

Please add at least the post score to the tag filter view, I don't see any reason for this to be absent. Ideally the tag filters would just look like any SE site, but with user-defined content across any SE site.

<sup>PS: adding live updates would be nice as well, the main sites had those for years now</sup>

Comment: I guess it's due to the load on the server/database this would cause: score and views change pretty fast, so it's not feasible to cache them for long time. And query to fetch them for all the questions, across sites, is really heavy. As for avatars, they are not always showing on the sites as well, e.g. homepage or search results.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't think many people are actually using the tag filters, so the load should be manageable. It's probably a tiny, tiny fraction of the main sites

Comment: Well, considering the filters lag many times for me, I think it's already pretty heavy... but yeah, only SE dev can come with actual numbers and decide if it's worth the extra load. Just saying that it's likely still a major factor.

Comment: Less than ten views per year for this question :-(