# Top questions for filter or tag — network-wide

Tags: support, tag-filters

When I have a [filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/370337/machine-learning), I can search for the questions network-wide that are newest or have the most recent activity.  When creating the filter, I can also see how often a certain tag is used on different sites.  But is there any way to get the top voted questions for my filter, network wide?  If this is not possible, is there a way to get the top voted questions for a specific tag, network wide?

Comment: Not possible... they even [don't show the score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297472/show-the-same-information-in-tag-filters-as-in-question-lists-on-the-main-sites), let alone sort by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to get the top voted questions for a specific tag, network wide?

It's relatively easy to build a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1070408/top-questions-for-tag-networkwide) for this, if you don't mind the results being up to 7 days old. [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1070408/top-questions-for-tag-networkwide?tagName=salt) are the top questions for the [salt] tag:

[image]